# Array in Swift Xcode

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, parentheses

I have an algorithm that intersects some array with Bool and give me back some other array. Now the problem is that the arrays I get has this form: 
`[[[[123.0,334.45]]],[[[342.35,2434.34]]],[[[...,...]]],....]`

Now how you can see there are too Square brackets, is there any way to remove the parentheses too ?
thanking you.

Comment: It's probably better to clean up your algorithm so it doesn't emit such a mess in the first please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whew, now that's nesting!

I counted the brackets, and used the appropriate number of `joined()` methods to flatten the array:

```
let array = [[[[123.0,334.45]]],[[[342.35,2434.34]]]]
let flatArray = Array(array.joined().joined().joined())
```

...gives:

```
[123, 334.45, 342.35, 2434.34]
```